# Constructing compositional self-referential lenses in Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

It's not that uncommon to have data with self-references in it.  This comes up in imperative programming for sure, but it also can show up in Haskell.  For example, one can have `IORef`s or `STRef`s as fields in a data type that point to the data type itself (and one can use `RecursiveDo` syntax or `mfix` to "tie the knot" on construction).

I was wondering if it is possible to do something similar using lenses.

Say I have some state of type `s` and a lens from `s` to some data contained in that state.  I'd like that contained data to *itself* have access to this lens, or in other words, I want the data within the state to be something like:

```hs
import Data.Lens

data Foo s = Foo
  { self :: Lens' s (Foo s)
  , fooData :: Int
  }

-- A silly `Show` instance so that we can print a few things
instance Show (Foo s) where
  show Foo{..} = "Foo <lens> "<>show fooData
```

This is a little challenging to use, but it can be made to work with a `Fix` type like:

```hs
newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }

fixIso :: Iso' (Fix f) (f (Fix f))
fixIso = iso unFix Fix
```

Now, I can make the following value:

```hs
myFoo :: Foo (Fix Foo)
myFoo = Foo fixIso 2
```

Here, we have a value of type `Foo (Fix Foo)` with a lens from its state to itself.

I can also create a pair of `Foo`s (by using `:*:` from `Generics`):

```hs
import GHC.Generics ((:*:)(..))

pairOfFoo :: (Foo :*: Foo) (Fix (Foo :*: Foo))
pairOfFoo = Foo (fixIso . _1) 2 :*: Foo (fixIso . _2) 4
```

This basically works, as in:

```
> pairOfFoo ^. _1
Foo <lens> 2
> pairOfFoo ^. _2
Foo <lens> 4
> Fix pairOfFoo ^. (self $ pairOfFoo ^. _1)
Foo <lens> 2
```

The bigger issue is that it feels like I should be able to create `pairOfFoo` *compositionally* from `myFoo`, but I don't see how to do it.  That is, I want to write something like:

```hs
pairOf :: (Extendable x, Extendable y) => x (Fix x) -> y (Fix y) -> (x :*: y) (Fix (x :*: y))
pairOf x y = extend x _1 :*: extend y _2

pairOfFoo = pairOf (Foo fixIso 2) (Foo fixIso 4)

class Extendable x where
  extend :: Lens' s' s -> x (Fix s) -> x (Fix s')
```

But this is where I'm stuck.  I don't know how to make an instance `Extendable Foo` (or even if that's the right signature).  I also think there should be an instance for `(Extendable x, Extendable y) => Extendable (x :*: y)` (or similar).  Or, maybe there's another strategy altogether?

---

#### Problem Extension

Now, let's say we have a second data type defined as such:

```hs
data Bar s = Bar
  { barSelf :: Lens' s (Bar s)
  , barFoo  :: Lens' s (Foo s)
  , barData :: String
  }
```

It's impossible to have a value of type `Bar (Fix Bar)` because `Bar` does not actually contain a `Foo`.  But, it's possible to make something like:

```hs
fooBar :: (Foo :*: Bar) (Fix (Foo :*: Bar))
fooBar = Foo (fixIso . _1) 2 :*: Bar (fixIso . _2) (fixIso . _1) "bar"
```

Additionally, it feels like it should be possible to have an instance `Extendable Bar`, so that we can use `fooBar` as an argument in `pairOf`.  Is this instance possible?

Comment: I'm finding it really hard to understand what your goal is here. I also don't see how these embedded lenses relate to the `IORef`s you mention in the introduction.

Comment: I have data types like `Foo` and `Bar` but that use `STRef`s instead of lenses, and I have various additional functions that read/write to these refs.  This works for my needs, but construction requires the use of `newSTRef`, a monadic action.  I thought it would be neat if, instead of using `STRef`s, I could use lenses.  Construction would then be the process of building up a data type (using functions like `pairOf`), and read/write would work via a simple `State` monad.  However, I couldn't make it work, and so I'm wondering if this is possible, or if not, why not.

Answer (score 3):

I guess maybe you want:

```
class Extendable a where
  extend :: Lens' (s' (Fix s')) (a (Fix s')) -> a (Fix s) -> a (Fix s')
instance Extendable Foo where
  extend l (Foo self x) = Foo (fixIso . l) x

pairOf :: (Extendable x, Extendable y)
  => x (Fix x) -> y (Fix y) -> (x :*: y) (Fix (x :*: y))
pairOf foo1 foo2 = extend _1 foo1 :*: extend _2 foo2

pairOfFoo = pairOf (Foo fixIso 2) (Foo fixIso 4)
```

It seems to work, and extends to more complicated compositions:

```
instance (Extendable x, Extendable y) => Extendable (x :*: y) where
  extend l (x :*: y) = extend (l . _1) x :*: extend (l . _2) y

example2 = pairOf (pairOf (Foo fixIso 2) (Foo fixIso 3)) (Foo fixIso 4)
```

Full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.Generics ((:*:)(..))
import Control.Lens

data Foo s = Foo
  { self :: Lens' s (Foo s)
  , fooData :: Int
  }

instance Show (Foo s) where
  show Foo{..} = "Foo <lens> " <> show fooData

newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }

fixIso :: Iso' (Fix f) (f (Fix f))
fixIso = iso unFix Fix

class Extendable a where
  extend :: Lens' (s' (Fix s')) (a (Fix s')) -> a (Fix s) -> a (Fix s')
instance Extendable Foo where
  extend l (Foo self x) = Foo (fixIso . l) x
instance (Extendable x, Extendable y) => Extendable (x :*: y) where
  extend l (x :*: y) = extend (l . _1) x :*: extend (l . _2) y

pairOf :: (Extendable x, Extendable y)
  => x (Fix x) -> y (Fix y) -> (x :*: y) (Fix (x :*: y))
pairOf foo1 foo2 = extend _1 foo1 :*: extend _2 foo2

pairOfFoo = pairOf (Foo fixIso 2) (Foo fixIso 4)
example2 = pairOf (pairOf (Foo fixIso 2) (Foo fixIso 3)) (Foo fixIso 4)
```

Comment: This is really great, and I definitely appreciate your effort.  However, I think I may have oversimplified the problem when I posted.  Specifically, the fact that you don't use `self` in the definition of `extend` for `Foo` seems problematic to my larger question.  I'll update my question with a slightly more involved example.